# Hebrew Culture does not have HebrewCalendar on Server

Tags: c#, .net-core, calendar, culture

I have a DateTime in the Gregorian Calendar, and I need to get the equivalent date in the Hebrew Calendar.

I then need to format the date as string, but it must include the Hebrew name of the month, preferably all in Hebrew text (ie, ט"ז אדר תשע"ט), though English is fine if it includes the name of the month (ie, 16 **Adar** 5779).

This is the code that I am trying:

```
public static string ToHebrewDateString(this DateTime value)
 {
     CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("he-IL");
     var calendar = new HebrewCalendar();
     cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = calendar;
     return value.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy", cultureInfo);
}
```

This works fine when I run locally. However, once deployed on my Azure server, I get this error:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Not a valid calendar for the given culture.
```

It seems as though the **HebrewCalendar** is not available for the **he-IL** culture for some reason.

My project is using dotnet core 2.2, and we use docker containers.
Would anyone know why this is happening and how I can resolve it?